# I have a single page real estate listing web app I created with AngularJS, decided to serve up data w/$http service, didn't work. Can anybody see why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below, are the following three files which I believe is where the issue originates. I know I could have probably used POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, but I am deliberately trying it with $http.

mansionsController.js file:

```
angular
    .module('ngMansions')
    .controller('mansionsController', function($scope, mansionsFactory) {

            $scope.mansions;

            mansionsFactory.getMansions().success(function(data) {
            $scope.mansions = data;
            }).error(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });      

});
```

mansionsFactory.js file:

```
angular
    .module('ngMansions')
    .factory('mansionsFactory', function($http) {


    function getMansions() {
        return $http.get('data/data.json');
    }

    return {
        getMansions: getMansions
    }

});
```

data.json file:

```
 [
        {
            "type": "Condo",
            "price": 220000,
            "address": "214 Grove Street",
            "description": "Excellent place, really nice view!"
        },
        {
            "type": "House",
            "price": 410500,
            "address": "7823 Winding Way",
            "description": "Beautiful home with lots of space for a large family."
        },
        {
            "type": "Duplex",
            "price": 395000,
            "address": "834 River Lane",
            "description": "Great neighborhood and lot's of nice green space."
        }
    ];
```

Comment: You'll need to provide the error or output that you got.

Comment: Thats the wierd part Bielski, I got nothing on the console for error. A blank page and a blank console, I hit reload and still nothing. The server is running fine, I get that split second flash of the listing before the screen goes blank but nothing appears on the console.

Comment: Can you paste your html or better create a plnkr ? It's tough to guess what's going wrong with these snippets

Comment: Curious, here is my plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/JXtds0A7HvTUHsEVbfKn?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0):

I had a semicolon at the end of the square bracket in my json file. These small details always get the best of me. Thank you all for your efforts.